# Erro ao fazer upload de Imagens com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, upload

Estou tentando usar Bootstrap Jasny's file upload(http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput) para fazer upload de fotos e salvar o nome da foto no BD com o Laravel 5.1 mas não está dando certo.

Aparentemente o laravel está capturando a foto quando dou o comando `dd(Request::capture());` ele traz os dados conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ele está mostrando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que seria nessa Linha

```
 $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
```

Segue o código

**View**

```
 <form method="post"  class="form-group" role="form" id="form"    action=".../perfil/update" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
<label>Imagem de Perfil &nbsp;</label>
 <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
 <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail">
  <img src="assets/upload/avatar/avatar.png" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail"></div>
 <div class="user-edit-image-buttons">
 <span class="btn btn-azure btn-file">
<span class="fileinput-new"><i class="fa fa-picture"></i> Selecione uma imagem</span>
<span class="fileinput-exists"><i class="fa fa-picture"></i>Trocar</span>
<input type="file" id="file" name="foto"> </span>
<a href="#" class="btn fileinput-exists btn-red" data-dismiss="fileinput">
<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function update()
    {

        $id = $this->request->get('id');
        $dadosForm = $this->request->except('_token');
        //
        //Recebe o Arquivo do Form
        $file = $this->request->file('foto');



        if($this->request->hasFile('foto') && $file->isValid()) {


            $destinationPath = '/upload/profile/';
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
            $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image
            $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path


        }



        if (isset($fileName)) $dadosForm = $this->associado->user_pic = $fileName;

        $this->associado->where('id', $id)->update($dadosForm);

    }
```

Comment: Dê um dd de $file antes do if

Comment: Ele traz a imagem
UploadedFile {#29 ▼
            -test: false
            -originalName: "Koala.jpg"
            -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
            -size: 780831
            -error: 0
          }

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque é aquele motivo que foi discutido no meta, onde a pergunta é um erro de digitação ou alguma confusão por parte do AP (como um erro de sintaxe ou colocar o índice errado no array), que dificilmente vai ajudar alguma pessoa, pois é um problema muito particular.

Comment: Bom @WallaceMaxters acho isso totalmente desnecessário pois aí em cima temos um Upload totalmente funcional poderia estar ajudando varias pessoas que estão procurando uma solução parecida.

Posso até apagar a postagem mas estaria sendo egoísta a ideia aqui é se ajudar e não desqualificar duvida de outras pessoas pois amanhã quem pode estar precisando de ajuda pode ser você

Comment: @BJJ eu só estou falando do rumo que a resposta tomou, não tem nada a ver com seu código ou sua pergunta. O título leva a entender que há um "erro com a imagem ao fazer o upload", mas sua resposta mostra que o problema era apenas um erro de digitação ou um simples erro de uso do índice do array. Não leve para o lado pessoal, estou apenas agindo dentro das recomendações do site

Comment: Inclusive tem até essa opção na hora de fechar, nem precisava de eu ter criado uma nova. Vacilo meu, o **fechamento de perguntas do site** já tem essa opção pronta para tais casos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido

O problema estava nas Linhas:

```
 $destinationPath = '/upload/profile/';
 if (isset($fileName)) $dadosForm = $this->associado->user_pic = $fileName;
```

Mudei para:

```
$destinationPath = 'assets/upload/profile/';
if (isset($fileName)) $dadosForm['user_pic'] = $fileName;
```